# Exporting a non functional XAMPP database?

Tags: mysql

I've been using XAMPP for several local projects.
A few days ago I installed Desktop Server for Wordpress local development.
Little did I realize, I wouldn't be able to open the regular xampp back up...
Now I need to export the databases I've created on xampp without being able to access the old phpmyadmin.

How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: If MySQL is running, you can either use MySQL Workbench or other equivalent tool to connect to the server. the host is probably `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Mysql is running via xampp lite which is built in desktop server. When I turn desktop server off I can't run xampp.

Comment: Is there anyway i can take some file from xampp and add it into desktop server?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have two MySQL instances on your machine. If one is using the MySQL networking port (3306), the other won't be able to start, which is consistent with what you're describing.

If you stop the one (from Desktop Server) then manually start the other one (in XAMPP, which you should be able to do from the XAMPP control panel), you can then connect to it and export your database.

You can't safely **merge** the two database data directories, but in theory if you completely stop both MySQL instances — and back everything up — you should be able to completely replace one datadir with the other. I don't generally advise this, because the possibility also exists to lose your data.